# Celery tasks not executed in Django app deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, celery-task

I've deployed my working django application on heroku. The whole application along with the celery tasks is working in local environment. But when I deploy it in heroku the tasks are not being run.

When I manually open `heroku python manage.py shell` and start the task from there, its running. The task is actually supposed to run when I click a button on a page. There it's not working.

Files for reference:

`myapp/celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os
from vms.settings import USE_ELASTIC_SEARCH

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'vms.settings')

app = Celery('vms', broker=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL','redis://localhost'), include=['cve.tasks','cpe.tasks'])

app.conf.update(
    result_backend='django-db',
    result_expires=86400*2,
    timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

`Procfile`

```
web: gunicorn vms.wsgi
worker: celery -A vms worker -l info
```

> [Edit] There are no errors in heroku log.

```
import os
import dj_database_url
import sys

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'blah blah'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost","127.0.0.1","blahblah.herokuapp.com"]


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'vms',
    'notifications',
    'cpe',
    'cve',
    'products',
    'django_celery_results',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vms.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vms.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
}

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='mysql://root:toor@localhost:3306/vms')

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
            )
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

USE_ELASTIC_SEARCH = os.environ.get('USE_ELASTIC_SEARCH','False') == 'True'
ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL = os.environ.get('ELASTICSEARCH_URL',"http://localhost:9200")
```

Comment: can you show your settings?

Comment: I've added settings file in the edit